# Relative layout simple positions

Tags: android, xml, layout, button, position

Ok I have a relative layout  inside a linear one.Until now,the relative layout was perfect,however now a big problem appeared.

A relative layout is based on the others item's position.For ex button2 is at the bottom of button1,and so on...and if button 1 disappears,button2 gets..."nuts".

That's my problem, when a button disappears one of the 4 buttons gets...up.
What I need is to position the buttons like this:

Button1 and button 2 at the middle of the screen,and 3 and 4 lower,but not really at the bottom.
I tried to modify it in relative layout but I failed...Hope you can help me.
Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <TextView 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:id="@+id/textView2" 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        </TextView>
        <Button 
        android:textSize="20dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button3" 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </Button>
        <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="74dp">
        </TextView>
        <Button 
        android:textSize="20dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button2" 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:textSize="20dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:paddingRight="30dp" 
        android:paddingBottom="90px" 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:padding="10dp" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button3">
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:textSize="20dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="bottom" 
        android:id="@+id/button4" 
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the code I use to make the button invisible:

```
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Button b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: possible snap of the problem please. It would be great

Comment: Somethimes,I must make on of the buttons invisible.When I do that,one of the other button just randomly changes it's position,because in it's code it appears that the buttons should be at the bottom of the button that got invisible.

Comment: +1 Agree with @Frankenstein, use View.INVISIBLE

Comment: It appears I need a cast,and I'm ussing buttons not views,because I need getText()

Comment: please post the code to show what are you doing...otherwise its too dificult to guess the problem..and yes "view" reffers to any view object

Comment: Look at the first post,that's the code I use that makes my buttons scramble like...

Comment: View.INVISIBLE is used in the Button instance, like `myButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: You should really read documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)`..then try `View.INVISIBLE`
here view = (your textview,button anything)

Answer (score 1):

Try to enhance your layout rules using:

```
    android:layout_toRightOf="component_id"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="component_id"
    android:layout_above="component_id"
    android:layout_below="component_id"
```

Or try to put the buttons in Table Layout... Something like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center"
android:padding="15dip">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" android:paddingLeft="20dip"
    android:paddingRight="20dip">
    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow android:paddingBottom="250dip">
            <Button android:id="@+id/edt1"
            android:layout_gravity="left" 
            android:text="Button1" 
            />

            <Button android:id="@+id/edt2" 
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="Button2"
            />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow> 
            <Button android:id="@+id/edt3"
            android:layout_gravity="left" 
            android:text="Button3"
            />
            <Button android:id="@+id/edt4"
            android:layout_gravity="right" 
            android:text="Button4"
            />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I mean - like that the buttons are isolated in "cells", although you will have to play with the table's layout params to achieve correct padding between elements

Comment: you don't get it,that's the problem! if I use one of those,and that component_id goes invisible,the buttons just randomly changes  it's position

Comment: I get your problem, what I was referring to is that if you have let's say 4 elements - 2 above (A and B) - 2 below (C and D). If you tell C to be below A (and not tell it be left of D), then if you remove A, C may go over B! But if you enhance your rules and tell it below A and left of D, C will always go over A's position. That's what I mean by "enhance your rules".